# SEC forms filed under different company name

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, canada, nasdaq

I'm trying to find 10-K, 10-Q, or 4 forms for a company called Creative Edge Nutrition (ticker symbol: FITX,) but what I found was forms filed under the name "LAUFER BRIDGE ENTERPRISES, INC." Why is this? Creative Edge is trying to get a medical marijuana license in Canada, although they are traded publicly in the US; I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

Here is what I've found: http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fitx/sec-filings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Google search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=creative%20edge%20nutrition%20laufner) will reveal many references to "Creative Edge Nutrition, formerly Laufner Bridge Enterprises". presumably the company changed its name but not its ticker symbol, and some reports refer to it by its old name. Some reports also refer to "Creative Edge Nutrition is a wholly owned subsidiary of Laufner Bridge Enterprises", so there may be a more complicated history - perhaps Laufner Bridge Enterprises used to be a holding company that owned Creative Edge.

Comment: Are there any implications to this that I should be worried about, or is it a fairly common procedure?